# Click a button manually, the browser goes to a new url; but when I run it using webdriver, it opens a new browser

Tags: java, browser, internet-explorer-8, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When I click a button manually, the browser (IE 8) goes to a new url; but when I run it using webdriver, it opens a new browser (IE 8). How can I make it go to the new url without opening a new browser?

```
driver.get(url);
driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
switchToFrame(frameName);
WebElement parent_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(parent_xpath));
WebElement child_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(child_xpath));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(parent_element).build().perform();
child_element.click(); //it opens a new browser if i run webdriver
```

Comment: Any code describing what you're trying to do?

Comment: driver.get(url); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
switchToFrame(frameName);
WebElement parent_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(parent_xpath));
WebElement child_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(child_xpath));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(parent_element).build().perform();
child_element.click(); //it opens a new browser if i run webdriver

Comment: Is the page publicly accesible so we can test it?

Comment: This definitely should not happen. With what technology is the page built? Can you show it to us, or make a similar demo page? Or just point to any public site with the same issue? What happend if you try in another browser? So. Many. Questions.

Answer (score 0):

I used this mechanism to stop selenium/webdriver to open a new window by getting href associated with the xpath. Then you can open the url in same window with selenium.open or driver.get and then you won't have to handle multiple windows. Here is the sample code:

String Xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/a";
String href = selenium.getAttribute("xpath=" + Xpath+ "@href");

selenium.open(href); // will open baseURL/href

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit hacky, I will say, you can try to String hrefMe=driver.getAttribute("href") for your link.
Then driver.get(hrefMe); Its not clicking, but do exactly the way you want it to do.